# Convert varchar to time datatype in DB2

Tags: sql, db2

I have a source table with column named "**created_time**" whose data type is varchar(22). I need to migrate timestamp value of this column to target table in **DB2** whose datatype is **TIME**. I tried different db2 timestamp and date related function but that's not working for me. Is there anyway I can directly convert it into the desired format?

```
Source Field Value : 7/1/2013 6:18:59 PM
Target Field Value : 06:18:59
```

***Edited***

I tried below statement as a starter

```
SELECT 
date(to_date(created_time,'DD-MM-YYYY HH:MI:SS'))
FROM table
```

Comment: What functions did you try and what were the details of the lack of success?

Comment: I tried this : SELECT 
date(to_date(column_with_date,'DD-MM-YYYY HH:MI:SS'))
FROM table

Comment: In DB2 `DATE` and `TIME` are different data types, and both are different from `TIMESTAMP`. If your target column has the `TIME` data type, you should not be using the function `DATE()`.

Comment: @mustaccio then how can I achieve the desired result? can you suggest someting?

Comment: Well, if the `DATE()` function fails to return `TIME`, then may by the `TIME()` function is worth a shot.

Comment: @mustaccio I tried that. Its not working.

Comment: What does that mean: "not working"? Is your computer turned on?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After lots for hit and trial following works for me. Posting this if anyone needs this just in case. I will accept the better answer than this is anyone have:

```
SELECT 
case 
                when length((substr(created_time, LOCATE(' ', created_time)))) = 12 
                then time(trim(substr(created_time, LOCATE(' ', created_time),10)))
                else time(trim(substr(created_time, LOCATE(' ', created_time),9)))
END time
FROM MY_TABLE
```

Comment: You can also use
`TIME( TIMESTAMP_FORMAT(created_time,'MM/DD/YYYY HH:MI:SS AM') )`